# Не работает звук <audio autoplay> </audio>

Tags: html, аудио

Вообщем создаю по приколу скример. Что бы так сказать напугать преподов в шараге :D

И атрибут autoplay не работает. В душе не знаю как это сделать! Помогите пожалуйста D:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <bgsound src="fsdsdfhh.mp3" loop>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Конкурс учебных заведений</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Конкурс учебных заведений ПМК против..." />
  </head>
  <body>

<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" style="display:none">
<source src="fsdsdfhh.mp3" type="audio/mp3" style="display:none">
Ваш web-браузер не поддерживает HTML элемент «<a style="display:none" href="/html/audio/">audio</a>».
</audio>

  <style>
  body {
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: 100%; /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  -webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
  -o-background-size: 100%; /* Opera 9.6+ */
  background-size: 100%; /* Современные браузеры */
}
  </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: вы используете Chrome? тогда прочитайте это "https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes"

Comment: Из-за таких приколов и отключили autoplay. А если и сработает, то в режиме mute (без звука).

Comment: А какой смысл одновременно controls="controls" и style="display:none" Если убрать и то и другое, плеер будет невидимым.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, заблокировали все лазейки, которые позволяли обойти этот запрет. Есть вариант - play во время прокрутки страницы: (будет ощущение, что музыка начала играть сама)

```js
document.onscroll = function(){audio.play()};
```

или повесить play на первый клик в любом месте страницы

```js
var first = true;
document.onclick = function(){
  if(first == true) audio.play()
  first = false;
}
```

Тогда товарищ возможно тоже не будет знать, что песня включилась от клика. Можно и воспользоваться автокликером: [результаты поиска автокликер](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&oq=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0j0i30l8.98640j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)